# Circular Generators hanging indefinately

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck, property-based-testing

I have a set of names in a file. I need to implement a Generator that iterates through them continually. However, the code is hanging indefinitely at `if (iter.hasNext)` after the first pass.

**Gen code**

```
var asStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/firstnames/female/en_US_sample.txt")

var source: BufferedSource = Source.fromInputStream(asStream)
var iter: Iterator[String] = Iterator.continually(source.getLines()).flatten

val genLastName: Gen[String] = {
  genCannedData
}

def genCannedData: Gen[String] = {
    println("Generating names: " + iter)
    Gen.delay {
      if (iter.hasNext) {
        println("In if")
        Gen.const(iter.next)
      }
      else {
        println("In else")
        Gen.const(iter.next)
      }
    }
}
```

**Sample Property test**

```
property("FirstNames") = {
    forAll(genLastName) {
      a => {
        println(a)
        a == a
      }
    }
  }
```

**en_US_sample.txt file contents**

```
Abbie
Abby
Abigail
Ada
Adah
```

**EDIT- Temporary working code**

The following code works if I recreate the iterator but I was wondering why `Iterator.continually` is hanging?

```
def genCannedData: Gen[String] = {
    Gen.delay {
      if (iter.hasNext) {
        Gen.const(iter.next)
      }
      else {
        asStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/firstnames/female/en_US_sample.txt")
        source = Source.fromInputStream(asStream)
        iter = source.getLines()
        Gen.const(iter.next)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first iteration, an iterator returned by `source.getLines()` returns false for `hasNext`, which means an empty iterator.
`Iterator.continually()` continually evaluate `source.getLines()` expecting a next iterator, but it continues to return an empty iterator. Then it forms an infinite loop.

Comment: Is there a better way to write it instead of reinitializing the stream as I've shown in the working code?

Comment: Create a list of entire elements (by `source.getLines().toList`) then `Iterator.continually(theList).flatten`. This way can be used only if it fits into memory. Otherwise re-initializing the stream is the way to go.